# UIPageViewController with segues

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, segue, pagecontrol

I'm using a UIPageViewController with a Page Control to display 3 pictures. Is it possible to link each picture to another ViewController? Like picture 1 -> news, picture 2 -> videos, ...
Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, you need to make the images 'touchable' and then apply segues from there. To make the images touchable is an option in the attributes pane inside of Interface Builder, you need to check `User Interaction Enabled`, then if I remember rightly build the segue the normal way.